# measuring gears for servo motors

Tags: rcservo

I'm quite new to mechanical engineering and not familiar with gears and motors. A few days ago, I bought a second-hand GWS servo motor for my project, and it didn't include gears.

Can someone help me understand the correct measurement of my motor so I can buy the correct **gear** to fit on my servo motor. Specifically, the measurement of the **gear hole**:

[image: GWS S35 Continuous rotation servo]

Comment: According to [Pololu S35 product page](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/948) this [tag:rcservo] has a *Futaba-compatible output shaft*, which you should be able to search the web on.

Answer (score 1):

That servo already has a gear train inside of it.  It's designed to have an arm attached to that output shaft.  The splines on the shaft need to be matched specifically to the servo arm.

You need to find arms that are meant to fit that servo.  If you can't find them at hobby shops, then try eBay or similar.

Comment: yes, but to find the gears online, i need to measure the output shaft, what is the standard way of measuring it? so i would know what specific gear specs i should look for.

Answer (score 1):

The output spline is generally proprietary, and will vary by manufacturer.

Measuring the diameter is generally not useful, although counting the teeth can help.  Really all you need to do is type the servo model number into google and see what arms match.

I did the legwork and the S35 uses the futuba spline, so any arm designed for a futuba servo in that size range will fit.